# How to write method which performs when user presses only Enter?

Tags: java, input, console

I want to write infinity while statement which will perform every time when user just presses `Enter`. Every stream readers I know perform when user enteres anything into console or presses `Enter` twice.

---

I want to write something like this:

> Console: 
>   output 1 [enter have been pressed onse] 
>   output 2 [enter have been pressed onse] 
>   output 3 [enter have been pressed onse] 
>   [so on...]

This is my current code:

```
addQuestionsInArray();

Random r = new Random();
DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(System.in);
while (true) {
    String question = questionsList.get(r.nextInt(questionsList.size()));
    System.out.println(question);
    if (String.valueOf(is.readInt()).equals("0")) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've written using a regular stream reader and why it's not working?

Comment: A Piece of code, What you have done will help answering.

Comment: User input is text, DataInputStream is for reading binary data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To wait for the user to hit enter, I usually do something like

```
new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
```

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Press enter.");
        new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
        System.out.println("Thanks.");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Press enter.
[enter]
Thanks.
```

---

Regarding your edit, I still suggest you use a `Scanner`. (`DataInputStream` should be used for binary data, not strings and characters written on `System.in`):

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

while (true) {
    String question = questionsList.get(r.nextInt(questionsList.size()));
    System.out.println(question);

    String input = s.nextLine();
    // int input = s.nextInt();    if you want integers

    if (input.equals("0"))
        break;

    // if (input == 0) break;      if you want integers
}
```

Comment: I guess he doesn't want waiting for user input, he wants a loop statement continues until user press `Enter` character.

Comment: By your demo code, at any execute loop statement, user has to enter a input character(s), do I said correctly?

Comment: Thank you very much! If every answer was as yours it will be an utopia ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can define a `Thread` that with specify timing interval check user input with `System.in.read()` statement and if equals with `Enter character /n/r` terminate main loop

Comment: It is one of the ways, but not is the best in this case ;)

Answer (score 1):

You would be looking for an [action listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) in this case.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590357/a-simple-question-regarding-actionlistener-and-enter-key) another SO question that addresses action listeners and the enter key.

Comment: Yes. If the goal is the press enter to print to console.